# redux reducer side-effects, reducer return value has a form that is different from the initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I bumped into a sort of interesting problem.
The use case is like this:

When rendering a profile (whether place / user profile), I want to retrieve some info from the server.
The reducer looks like this:

```
import {
    FETCH_PLACE_SUCCESS,
} from './GetPlaceActions';

const initialState = {};

/**
 * This reducer keeps track of all places that have previously been retrieved
 * If the store contains a place that has already been added, it will return it
 * @param previousState
 * @param type
 * @param payload
 * @returns {*}
 * @constructor
 */
const GetPlaceReducer = (previousState = initialState, { type, payload }) => {

    let place = null;

    switch (type) {
      case FETCH_PLACE_SUCCESS:
          place = payload.place;
          previousState[place.placeId] = place;
          return { ...place };

      default:
          if (payload && payload.placeId) {
            place = { ...previousState[payload.placeId] }
          }
          return { ...place };
    }
};
```

The idea here is to keep track of profiles that have previously been fetched.
I feel that the reducer should not contain information about the 'current' place, because current state can refer to the wrong (previous profile), and they should be isolated as mistakes are easily made.
When using SSR, it is very well possible that this state object would already contain a profile in the store when it arrives at the client, hence I wouldn't need to refetch it again.

The problem I have with this approach is that this is not a pure function, and the state returned does not have the same form of the initial state (the initial state is a collection, whereas the reducer returns a single place).

What I effectively do here, is update the 'object of places' which is a side effect, and I only return a single place (the on I need in my component).
While I think this will work, I'm not convinced that this is the best way.

How could you improve the existing design?

Comment: You could add another collection in state to hold previously fetched profiles and associated metadata.

Comment: @DovRine I could. But returning this collection to every component that needs specific profile info isn't very useful. Another thing I thought about was having a second reducer, but this adds additional complexity, and I'm not sure it's worth it.

Comment: The components only subscribe to the state they need. Adding another state key here shouldn't affect any component that doesn't explicitly ask for it.

Comment: @DovRine Could you formulate an answer with what you have in mind exactly?

Comment: Not until later this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

The given example does not work as one would expect, because the return value in the switch statement will always update the current state.
Therefore it is not a good practise to return a value in a format that is different from the initial state as it results in inconsistent state.

For my use case the solution was pretty simple.
As the currently displayed profile contains information that requires live information (i.e. how many watchers are there for the profile), I need to request the data again on every page view.

The way I isolate the state from one profile against another, is by returning an empty object on `FETCH_PLACE_REQUEST`. This ensures that the state is always emptied when a new profile is requested.